# Haskell, Create a function given a specific type

Tags: haskell, lambda, types

I read many similar topics and still don't understand.
So the question is to create a function that has a specific type
for example given type `Integer-> Integer` a function that has that type is `\x-> x+1`. How to find lambda functions for the following types:

1. `(((Int → a) → a) → b) → b`
2. `(a -> b) -> c`
3. `a → (a → a)`
4. `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`

I solved 4. by guessing:

```
\f g a -> f (g a)
```

Three variables after lambda, `f` which has type `b->c`, `g` has type `a->b`, and `a` has type `a`.

`:t \f g a -> f (g a)`

I don't really get the steps just that there are inputs of type `b->c`, `a->b` and `a`. Then I guessed the order.

For 1. there is just one input so it should be `\f-> \g->...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the best ways to solve these exercises in practice is to use *holes*: write `_` for a hole to be filled and read from GHCi about the type of that hole

```
> foo :: (((Int -> a) -> a) -> b) -> b ; foo = _
    * Found hole: _ :: (((Int -> a) -> a) -> b) -> b
```

The hole is a function. Let's use a lambda then.

```
> foo :: (((Int -> a) -> a) -> b) -> b ; foo = \f -> _
    * Found hole: _ :: b
    * Relevant bindings include
        f :: ((Int -> a) -> a) -> b
```

The hole must have type `b`. No more lambdas. We can't create a value of type `b`, unless we somehow apply `f` (note the printed type of `f`).

```
> foo :: (((Int -> a) -> a) -> b) -> b ; foo = \f -> f _
    * Found hole: _ :: (Int -> a) -> a
```

Ah, now the hole is a function again. Another lambda.

```
> foo :: (((Int -> a) -> a) -> b) -> b ; foo = \f -> f (\g -> _)
    * Found hole: _ :: a
    * Relevant bindings include
        g :: Int -> a
```

Well, now we need to produce `a`. With `g :: Int -> a` at our disposal it looks easy.

```
> foo :: (((Int -> a) -> a) -> b) -> b ; foo = \f -> f (\g -> g 42)
```

No more holes -- done.

---

Note that your 2) `(a -> b) -> c` is impossible to realize properly -- there is no way to produce a `c` from that input. You can only write non-terminating (or crashing) programs with that type.

Answer (score 0):

`(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` represents a function with 3 polymorphic parameters, first 2 parameters are also functions, first one is `b -> c` (function accepting b  and returning c) and second one is `a -> b` (function accepting a and returning b)  (see [higher order functions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions)). Lambda `\f g a -> f (g a)` has three parameters and is implemented by result of calling `g` with parameter `a` passed to `f`.